# smash product of Eilenberg-Maclane spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $K_n=K(G,n)$ be the Eilenberg-Maclane space. How to obtain $K_m\wedge K_n$ is $(m+n-1)$-connected? (Hatcher's book page 404)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct $K(G, n)$ by starting with $n$-cells and then attaching cells of higher dimension to kill the homotopy groups above dimension $n$; do the same for $K(G, m)$. The smash product will then have no cells below dimension $n + m$.